# Auto play and stop html5 audio with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, audio, playback

i have a little problem.

I have a facebook like box window on overlay. This box hide when user click like - obviously. I wanna to use audio element when this window is visible and stop audio when this window will be hide.
So this is my html and jquery. Please help me.

```
<audio id="audio_player" loop="loop">
    <source src="fileadmin/templates/main/crowd.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"'>
    <source src="fileadmin/templates/main/crowd.ogg" type='audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"'>
</audio>

$(document).ready(function(){
function audio_player (){
    if (
        $('fb_like_box').css('display','block')){
            $('audio').each(function() {
                var song = $(this);
                    song.play();
                });
    }
    else if (
        $('fb_like_box').css('display','none')) {
            $('audio').each(function() {
                var song = $(this);
                    song.pause();
                });
    }
    else {}
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code syntactically wrong.

First of all, the following syntax is for assigning value.

```
$('#fb_like_box').css('display','block')
```

It assigns the property `block` to element `$('#fb_like_box');`

If you want to check it, as that, you have use something like this:

```
if($('#fb_like_box').css('display') == 'block') {
    // then do something
}
```

A good way to do what you are attempting is:

```
if ($('#fb_like_box').is(':visible')) {

    $('audio').each(function() {
        $(this).play();
    });

} else {

    $('audio').each(function() {
        $(this).pause();
    });

}
```

Comment: http://mylovedcreation.pl/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Zrzut-ekranu-2012-06-4-o-11.06.42.png

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski, Your selector is `$(".fb_like_box")`

Answer (score 1):

try something very basic like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('audio')[0].play();
}
```

If this runs, than at least you know you are on the right track. 
Once you know you can play it, add the conditionals, and then test that they are working.

Answer (score 0):

Use [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector and add `.` or `#` according to what `fb_like_box` is. `fb_like_box` is not a valid selector. Assuming it's an ID

```
if ($('#fb_like_box').is(':visible')){
      // like box visible, play audio
            $('audio').each(function() {
                var song = $(this);
                    song.play();
                });
    }
    else {
      // like box hidden pause audio  
            $('audio').each(function() {
                var song = $(this);
                    song.pause();
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you should run the function when at the moment that the facebook field is hidden, therefore, you need to add the function to de adequate listener.
I think that in this situation it would be '`DOMAttrModified`':

Some pseudocode(not tested code):

```
$('facebookelementtohide').addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', function(e){
   audio_player ();
}, false);
```